# how to use cascade in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

```
create table loginDetails(
 userId   varchar(30),
 cellPhoneNo    varchar(10),    
 displayName  varchar(20),
 password   varchar(20),
 secretQuestion varchar(50),
 secretAnswer varchar(50),
 joiningDate    date,
 foreign key(userId) references userDetails(userId) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

the error is come on use in oracle.

```
foreign key(userId) references userDetails(userId) on delete cascade on update
```

cascade
                                                                      *

> ERROR at line 9:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

This query is working on mysql but in oracle is not working? please anyone tell me how it work in oracle.

Comment: For starters, syntax isn't identical between vendors (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc).  The "S" in "SQL" stands for "Structured", sadly not "Standardized".  Though ANSI is working to improve that, support and performance aren't always ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not support cascading updates of primary keys.  The primary key ought to be both unique and immutable so it shouldn't ever need to change.  Since you should never be updating a primary key, there should be no need to cascade those updates.

In general, you probably also ought to use the `VARCHAR2` data type rather than `VARCHAR`.  Currently, those data types are identical but Oracle may change the semantics of the `VARCHAR` type in the future to cause the empty string to be treated differently from `NULL`.  Assuming you don't want your application to potentially break in the future when those semantics change, it would be safer to use `VARCHAR2`.